# C# Math Round -11.5 to 11 and round -11.6 to 12

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am testing an application with Selenium and C#. This application performs the following rounding (which I think are javascript rounding standards):

- -11.51 rounds to -12
- -11.5 gets rounded towards zero, so it goes to -11
- 11.5 rounds up to 12

This is based on required specifications, so I have to calculate numbers and round myself to come at this end result you see above. I have to use C# libraries to round them. Using AwayFromZero for the positive numbers works, but I cant seem to find a valid solution to round my negative numbers.

For instance, using AwayFromZero, ToEven, or Floor for negatives, I get:

- -11.51 to -12
- -11.5 to -12

Using Ceiling and Truncate, I get:

- -11.51 to -11
- -11.5 to -11

In Summary, I need an algorithm or some way to be able to round towards zero when my number is -.5 or *above*, or -10.5 or *above*, for instance. I also need this same algorithm for rounding -10.51 to -11

Comment: What is your problem? This sounds like correct behavior.

Comment: Rounding `-10.5` *AWAY* from 0 is `-11`. Think of a number line.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining my problem clearly enough. The first part in my original post explains how the Application is rounding negatives. My second part explains how I can not round to match the application using any C# libraries

Comment: The problem is he wants `AwayFromZero` for all positive numbers, but for negitive numbers he wants a non-existant `TowardZero` option.

Comment: That is correct, @ScottChamberlain

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement your own rounding alg if you need to follow specific requirements that are not supported by .NET.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, No, Ceiling will not accomplish what I want

Comment: I edited my post, and inserted a summary at the end, which clarifies my goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
public static double MyRound( double x )
{
    return Math.Floor( x + 0.5 );
}
```

This seems to satisfy all your test cases.

Comment: I am pretty sure the math does work out to be exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This may work, however my type I am working with is a decimal. When I change that method to decimal, it says "operator + cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and double"

Comment: @MikeJohnston change `0.5` to `0.5m` [that m marks the number as a decimal instead of a double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx#Anchor_0).